# How to use a variable as an argument of ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's consider the following example.

`Dat` is a data frame with variables y, a, b, and c.

I would like to create three scatter plots where y is on the y axis and a, b, or c is on the x axis.

I used a `for` loop as follows.

I know `x = x` in `aes(x = x, y = y)` is wrong. My question is how to modify x = x to make it work.

```
library(ggplot2)

x_vec = c("a", "b", "c")

a = 1:10
b = a+10
c = b+10
y = 1:10

Dat = data.frame(y = y, a = a, b = b, c = c)
str(Dat)

p_list = list()

for (i in 1:3) {
    # i = 1
    x = x_vec[i]
    x
    p = ggplot(Dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        geom_point()
    p_list[[i]] = p
}

plot(p_list[[1]])
plot(p_list[[2]])
plot(p_list[[3]])
```

Comment: This is programming rather than statistics

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`

```
...
    p = ggplot(Dat, aes(x=!! rlang::sym(x), y=y))+
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not take advantage of ggplot's functionality?

Once your data is in long format it's easier to create small multiples across each category. This answer assumes you want three *separate* scatterplots. Try this out:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

a = 1:10
b = a + 10
c = b + 10
y = 1:10

dat <- data.frame(y = y, a = a, b = b, c = c)

dat_long <- dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = `a`:`c`, names_to = "labels", values_to = "x") %>%
  arrange(labels)

ggplot(dat_long, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_wrap(~ labels)
```

[image: small multiples]

If you *must* execute this using a `for` loop, then see the accompanying answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your alternative solution is better than mine with a for loop.